# How to call pending web services, when network is connected in android?

Tags: android, web-services

I am working with web services, I am successful in retrieving data from Server. Everything works fine, when device is connected to network.

If network is not available when I call a web service, it has to be in pending state. And as soon as network is connected I have to call these pending web services.

I felt like one solution is using Broadcast receiver to know network status. But how to call web service at that particular time?

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Please comment & down vote, so I can learn something from it

Answer (score 0):

You can use the BroadcastReceiver to start the web services.

Add a receiver to your manifest.

```
<receiver
   android:name="com.example.appname.ConnectivityBroadcastReceiver"
   android:label="ConnectivityBroadcastReceiver" >
   <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Then create the ConnectivityBroadcastReceiver class which extends BroadcastReceiver.

```
public class ConnectivityBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
             // check here if you are connected
             // if you are start your web services
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First check network connection. If it is connected then execute httpclient request. If it is not connected, execute it when connected. The class below will inform you when it is connected.

```
public class ConnectionChangeListener extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        NetworkInfo info =  ((ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)).getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (info != null && info.isConnected() && info.isAvailable()) {
            Log.i("NetworkInfo","connected");
        } else {
            Log.i("NetworkInfo","not connected");

        }
    }
}
```